# Grep/Regex matching across a fixed pattern across a multiple lines with special conditions on matching

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

I have a problem where I need to identify each occurrence of a problem within many files. The occurrence is determined based on a pattern across multiple lines.

In my case I'm trying to identify literals that have a leading space, contains more than a single consecutive space character or is preceded by a set of known small words (e.g. 'or', 'and', etc). Literals are determined by the single quote. However I'm only interested in literals where four lines before hand the line contains the word "LITERAL".

Here are some examples for the contents of a file:

```
EXEC LITERAL
    LEVEL
    NAME
    LENGTH
    VALUE (' Foo')
END EXEC

EXEC LITERAL
    LEVEL
    NAME
    VALUE ('Foo  Bar')
END EXEC

EXEC LITERAL
    LEVEL
    NAME
    VALUE ('Bar Foo')
END EXEC

EXEC LITERAL
    LEVEL
    NAME
    VALUE ('Foo')
END EXEC

EXEC LITERAL
    LEVEL
    NAME
    LENGTH
    VALUE ('or Bar')
END EXEC

EXEC DEFINITION
    LEVEL
    NAME
    LENGTH
    VALUE ('Bar')
END EXEC
```

In the above example I would want the output to identify the file and list occurrences of 'Foo', 'Foo  Bar' and 'or Bar'. Note that 'Bar Foo' is not included as any spaces used to separate words within the quotes are acceptable if it's a single space.

I've been able to construct grep statements that allow me to identify instances of multiple spaces, leading spaces and containing a small word (via multiple pipes), however I cannot seem to use grep for regex. I saw mentioned in another article about using [pcregrep](http://linuxcommand.gds.tuwien.ac.at/man_pages/pcregrep1.html) to support regex in grep. I'm happy to do that, but I'm a tad lost with the regex expression to use.

So far I've got to the following command:

```
pcregrep -M 'LITERAL.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*VALUE.* ' test.txt
```

Unfortunately it doesn't pick up the 'Foo  Bar' example (because of the 4 x \n I presume). The next one picks up 'Foo  Bar' but doesn't pick up 'or Bar':

```
pcregrep -M 'LITERAL.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*VALUE.* ' test.txt
```

Also when I was testing with larger data sets it would pick up LITERAL when it doesn't meet the above patterns (e.g. it's part of another word unrelated to the above). I really need the expression to restrict matches to the given patterns, ignoring instances of VALUE or LITERAL that do not form the above example patterns.

Any help in how to resolve this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat file.txt | awk '/LITERAL/ {print}' FS="\n" RS="" | grep -v "END"
```

you can have the full list with END

```
 cat file.txt | awk '/LITERAL/ {print}' FS="\n" RS=""
```

Comment: While that works if the file only contains the values in my question, when other data is in the file it doesn't work. I'm trying to find the patterns from my question in a file full of other stuff. My apologies if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could 
1. specify a word boundary `\b` in front of `LITERAL` to avoid false positives
2. Instead of fixing the number of newlines in the regex, specify a non-greedy match for `.` or `\n`

```
pcregrep   -M '\bLITERAL(?:(?!VALUE).|\n)*?VALUE[[:blank:]]*\('"'(?=.*[[:blank:]].*).*?'\)" file.txt
```

Comment: That is almost there, however it's picking up 'Foo'. Can it be modified where there is a space after the first single quote or two spaces between the single quotes for the same line as the VALUE? This way it would ignore 'Foo' and would meet what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Metalskin, the revised version checks for the presence of at least a single space between the parentheses after `VALUE`. Not as specific as you need it to be but as you can see the regex is as it is spiralling out of control...

Comment: so very close! One last problem (which is my fault as it's not in the examples given), if I have "Foo Bar" then it's picked up. I need to exclude ones where a single space occurs between the single quotes but is not a leading or trailing space within the quote (if that makes sense). I'll update my question so it's clearer. 

Ahh, just saw where you said it's not as specific as I need. If you haven't got the time I'll try and fiddle with the regex to sort it out.